# Install plugins in Eclipse PDE

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-pde

I am using a plugin for the Eclipse PDE 4.6 as an IDE for a language. To start the IDE, I run Eclipse and go to Run / Run Configurations, select Eclipse Application, and use the default settings. In Eclipse, I can install the marketplace and other plugins just fine, but none of the plugins show up in the new window. I used this link to install marketplace: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/staging/ However, there is still no marketplace under the Help menu. How do I install marketplace and other plugins in the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'Run > Run Configurations' select your application and then go to the 'Plug-ins' tab.

In 'Launch with' select 'all workspace and enabled target plug-ins'.

Also check 'Add new workspace plug-ins in the launch configuration automatically'

You will also need to have 'Running Platform' selected in the Preferences in 'Plug-in Development > Target Platform'.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was getting color-theme and I had to set its color before running the IDE otherwise it wouldn't show up, maybe I was doing something wrong.